# Super Mutant Behemoth, Anyone?

Tags: fallout-shelter

I have level-50 max-SPECIAL-stat character occupied with Minuteman Uniform and Focused Gatling Laser and still don't stand a chance against Super Mutant Behemoth.
Anyone --with successful story against SMB-- care to share their story?

Comment: Even the best dwellers lose to behemoths sometimes. I would expect the one you to describe to kill maybe half of them. What's the Minuteman Uniform do again?

Comment: @DCShannon Minuteman Uniform is one of two legendary armors that gives +8 total stat points (+2S, +2P, +2I, +2A) instead of the usual 7.

Comment: You could use the T-60 Power Armour, instead. It gives a huge boost to Endurance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's always a random element to it… even some of my dwellers with better gear than yours struggle with lesser enemies, such as Enclave Deathclaw or Super Mutants.

According to this [writeup](https://www.reddit.com/r/foshelter/comments/3hovds/everything_we_know_so_far_on_wasteland_exploration/), the formula that determines success in an encounter is as follows:

```
level / 2 + random(0, stat) + random(0,stat) + random(damage min, damage max)
```

Where `stat` is the stat the encounter tests against (each enemy is "weak" to single stat). 
The calculated value of above formula is then compared to a difficulty value of the encounter (if yours is higher, you win the encounter).

I wasn't able to find which stat SMBs are weak to though.

So overall, an armor with +2 to four different stats is really useful, as it raises your chances to win several different encounters. +2 to Endurance is an additional benefit, as it will make your dweller immune to radiation (Piper's armor comes to mind).

The only thing you can do to improve your chances of beating SMBs is to get a better weapon and maybe a Pet that does +X to damage.